# Make one dropbox whose contents depend on the value in another dropbox in tkinter python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, openpyxl

I am making a GUI application that reads and writes excel sheets using "openpyxl" and "tkinter" (py3) libraries.

I have 2 dropboxes (I am using "tkinter.ttk.OptionBox" but if you want to suggest some other widget, then go ahead). I want one dropbox to have the names of the sheets that are there in an Excel workbook and the second dropbox to have the column headers of that sheet. I have made a browse button for the user to browse the excel file and also I want to open/load the excel workbook minimum number of times to increase efficiency. Also, the files that will be used would be pretty big.

I have done this (refer to the code) but the problem is that when I change the sheet name in one dropbox, in the other dropbox the column headers do not change, instead they remain as the column header of the first sheet. I have searched for it online but could not find anything worth using. I would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

```py
self.dropdownMain1Var = StringVar()
self.dropdownMain2Var = StringVar()
wbb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
wbb_worksheets = wbb.worksheets
for i in range(len(wbb_worksheets)):
    wbb_worksheets[i] = str(wbb_worksheets[i]).split('"')[-2]

self.dropdownMain1Var.set(wbb_worksheets[0])
self.dropdownMain1 = OptionMenu(self.topFrame, self.dropdownMain1Var, *wbb_worksheets)
self.dropdownMain1.grid(row=5, column=0)

columnheaders = list((str(i) + ".) " + wbb[self.dropdownMain1Var.get()].cell(row=1, column=i).value) for i in
range(1, wbb[self.dropdownMain1Var.get()].max_column + 1))

self.dropdownMain2Var.set(columnheaders[0])
self.dropdownMain2 = OptionMenu(self.topFrame, self.dropdownMain2Var, *columnheaders)
self.dropdownMain2.grid(row=8, column=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to monitor the change of your `OptionMenu`. This can be done by tracing your `StringVar`:

```
self.dropdownMain1Var.trace("w",function_to_change_other_OptionMenu)
```

Or you can use `ttk.Combobox` and use the `ComboboxSelected` event to update:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

l1 = {"Excel A":["Column A","Column B","Column C"],"Excel B":["Column 1","Column 2"]} #make a dict from your excel & sheet names

a = ttk.Combobox(root,value=[k for k in l1],state="readonly")
a.pack()

b = ttk.Combobox(root,state="readonly")
b.pack()

def change_box(event=None):
    b["values"] = l1.get(a.get())
    b.current(0)

a.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",change_box)

root.mainloop()
```